# ThreadLocal safety in Weblogic threadpool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'm writing an app which uses MDBs, EJBs and needs ThreadLocal to pass and log a variable across multiple EJBs and Helper classes until the transaction is complete.

The flow is

Starting with MDB onMessage() 
-> some business delegate EJBs
-> some helpers

Question:

This app runs within Weblogic and Weblogic re-uses Threads from within it's ThreadPool. So is there a possibility of data corruption across threads? Is the solution to use `ThreadLocal.remove()` safe enough?

Is there an alternative to ThreadLocal other than passing around the Object as a parameter to all methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reliably use a ThreadLocal in the EJB tier.  Even if your code seems to 'work' now, what happens if someone deploys one of your beans remotely? From [EJB Restrictions](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html):

> **Why is thread creation and management disallowed?**
>
> The EJB specification assigns to the EJB container the responsibility
>   for managing threads. Allowing enterprise bean instances to create and
>   manage threads would interfere with the container's ability to control
>   its components' lifecycle. Thread management is not a business
>   function, it is an implementation detail, and is typically complicated
>   and platform-specific. Letting the container manage threads relieves
>   the enterprise bean developer of dealing with threading issues.
>   Multithreaded applications are still possible, but control of
>   multithreading is located in the container, not in the enterprise
>   bean.

If you need to share state, you should pass it in to the EJB method as a parameter.  Is there a reason this approach won't work for you?  Another option would be to temporarily dump it into a transaction enlisted database or cache.

Comment: Yes, our alternative is to pass it as a parameter. But this object needs to traverse through over 15 method calls, so it pollutes all our interfaces and implementations. We would like to keep it non-intrusive - it is actually a Logging object and mandated by the organization

Comment: I don't think you're alone in this, it seems to be a pretty common pattern.  While unfortunate, it kind of flies in the face of the whole purpose of a component framework like EJB.  After all, you're not passing around transaction or security state to every method call, why would you be passing logging state?  That said, if you do go the parameter route, I would encourage you to put this information in a more robust container like a CallingContext object and pass that around instead.  Then, when you need to add the next great thing(tm) you don't have to refactor all your interfaces.

Answer (score 7):

WebLogic does not reset user set ThreadLocal variables when the thread is returned back to the pool - the user is responsible for managing them. When such threads are reused, its likely they will interfere. You may run into memory leaks since the thread local reference isn't cleaned up. You can safely reset your thread locals prior to returning the thread back to the container. The ThreadLocal.remove() call should clean it up (ensure that its done in a finally block)

Note that if any async or rmi calls are involved, your thread locals will not propagate. You may want to consider the WebLogic WorkArea feature  which allows context propagation across threads, clients & servers. More details can be found at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/context.htm#i1058690

Answer (score 1):

@JoseK: though I have not tried what you described in your issue, but here are my thoughts:-

1. Both MDB and Session beans are thread-safe. It means let us say if there is pool of 10 beans, only 10 requests will be handled simultaneously. Other requests would be queued for their turn. So one running thread local data should not interfere with other thread.
2. If you confident to use always local EJBs in future also, then I don't really see any issue in using thread local data. Because you are not really creating threads.
3. Though weblogic provides thread from thread-pool but that thread is given dedicately to each request flow, I don't think its local data should become corrupted ever.
4. As I said I have not tried myself, what I would try is:-

In MDB layer(your first layer), do Thread.getCurrentThread.setName(name)
and in subsequent layers print thread names like Thread.getCurrentThread.getName)

Perform multiple runs with different size of ejb pool, thread pool. Give a different thread name to each request flow. Try running multiple requests same time. And see if you ever get thread name mixed.

5.Having said above, to keep things simpler and furture remote EJB support, I would also pass CallingContext Interface to each layer.